# Custom addtocart to a specific place

Tags: magento2, addtocart, custom

How do I add addtocart programatically with quantity in a specific place?

a working code where block is extended from product View block but is too much code inside

```
<?php
$buttonTitle = __('Add to Cart');
$postDataHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper');
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');

if ($currentProduct = $block->getProduct()) {
    $variants = $block->getVariants($currentProduct);

    if($variants) { ?>
        <div id="product_variants">
        <?php foreach ($variants as $_product) : ?>
            <form action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getSubmitUrl($_product) ?>" method="post"
                        class="product_addtocart_variant"<?php if ($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
                      <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getId() ?>" />
                      <input type="hidden" name="selected_configurable_option" value="" />
                      <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />

                  <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
                  <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('form_top'); ?>
                  <div class="box-tocart">
                      <div class="variant-info">
                          <strong><?php echo  $_product->getName(); ?></strong>
                          <span>Artikelnummer: <?php echo  $_product->getSku(); ?></span>
                      </div>
                      <div class="fieldset">
                          <div class="variant-container">
                              <div class="variant-price">
                                  <span>Brutto: <?php echo  $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data')->currency(number_format($_product->getPrice()),true,false); ?> <?php echo  $_product->getCurrency(); ?></span>
                                  <span>Netto: </span>
                              </div>
                              <div class="quantity">
                                  <div class="control">
                                      <input type="number"
                                             name="qty"
                                             id="qty"
                                             maxlength="12"
                                             value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductDefaultQty($_product) * 1 ?>"
                                             title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty"
                                             data-validate="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                                      />
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="actions">
                                  <button type="submit"
                                          title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $buttonTitle ?>"
                                          class="action primary tocart"
                                          id="product-addtocart-button">
                                      <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $buttonTitle ?></span>
                                  </button>
                                  <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </form>
            <script>
                require([
                    'jquery',
                    'Magento_Catalog/js/price-box'
                ], function($){
                    var priceBoxes = $('[data-role=priceBox]');

                    priceBoxes = priceBoxes.filter(function(index, elem){
                        return !$(elem).find('.price-from').length;
                    });

                    priceBoxes.priceBox({'priceConfig': <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsonConfigVariants($_product) ?>});
                });
            </script>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>

        <?php if ($block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
                {
                    ".product_addtocart_variant": {
                        "Magento_Catalog/product/view/validation": {
                            "radioCheckboxClosest": ".nested"
                        }
                    }
                }
        </script>
        <?php else : ?>
        <script>
            require([
                'jquery',
                'mage/mage',
                'Magento_Catalog/product/view/validation',
                'Magento_Catalog/js/catalog-add-to-cart'
            ], function ($) {
                'use strict';

                $('.product_addtocart_variant').mage('validation', {
                    radioCheckboxClosest: '.nested',
                    submitHandler: function (form) {
                        var widget = $(form).catalogAddToCart({
                            bindSubmit: false
                        });

                        widget.catalogAddToCart('submitForm', $(form));
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php };
    }
?>
```

Comment: specific place? mean

Comment: product.info.details

Comment: Have u tried something?

Comment: yes a lot of things: i have a working case but is too much code